# Pegando valor input com jQuery

Tags: jquery

Não estou conseguindo pegar o valor digitado em um campo de input com jQuery:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="vendaMediaMensal" name="vendaMediaMensal">
```

jQuery:

```
var vendaMediaMensal = $("#vendaMediaMensal").val();

$("#vendaMediaMensal").focusout( function(){
    alert(vendaMediaMensal);
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O problema é que você está pegando o valor antes dele existir. Deixe para pegar o `.val()` somente no `focusout`:

```
var vendaMediaMensal = $("#vendaMediaMensal");
vendaMediaMensal.focusout( function(){
    alert(vendaMediaMensal.val());
});
```

Comment: É verdade, eu tinha esquecido desse detalhe.
E o valor que eu digitar no campo, terei que converter para currency se eu quiser calcular com outros valores ou não há necessidade?

Comment: Bom, não existe currency como tipo em JavaScript. No seu caso você vai usar provavelmente um `parseFloat(valor)`.

Answer (score 2):

Coloque a var dentro da função:

```
$("#vendaMediaMensal").focusout(function(){
        var vendaMediaMensal = $("#vendaMediaMensal").val();
        alert(vendaMediaMensal);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Apenas como melhoria recomendo utilizar o:

```
 $(this).val();
```

Assim você promove a reusabilidade deste evento.

Abraços